# Why does "unless" mean "if not"?

Tags: logic, terminology

Harry Gensler. [*Introduction to Logic*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138910597) (2017 3 ed). p 169.

> “Unless” is also equivalent to “if not”; so we also could use “(∼B ⊃ D) (“If you
> don’t breathe, then you’ll die”).”

Nicholas JJ Smith, [*Logic: The Laws of Truth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691151636) (2012). p 115.

> The statement “P unless Q” means that if Q is not true, P is true—so we
> translate it as $¬ \, Q→P$.

Using solely the original meaning of "unless" below, please expound why? How does definition 1 below $\equiv$ if not?  [*OED* Third Edition, June 2017](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075). [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLrR.jpg).

> †**A.** adv. Only in conjunctional phrases followed by *than* or *that*.
>
> 1. Forming a conjunctional phrase introducing a case in which an exception to a preceding negative statement (expressed or implied) will or may exist: (not) on a less or lower condition, requirement, etc., *than* (what is specified). *Obsolete*.

Comment: The OED link does not work; no one can see what's there unless someone fixes it...

Comment: Why should an answer about modern usage reference only an obsolete usage which requires a "than" or "that" not often found in modern usage? Or are you looking for a history of its changing uses over time?

Comment: Indeed, @aschepler , the Oxford definition seems singularly unhelpful.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry. Can you access it now?

Comment: @aschepler Yes. I'm pining to see how definition 1 becomes equivalent to "if not".

Comment: 1.  OED links are available to individual or institutional subscribers only.  Please do not use links on Math.SE that are behind paywalls.  2.  By OED convention, I believe any sense preceded by a dagger (the † symbol) is **obsolete**.  It may therefore not be a suitable basis for determining a technical meaning.  In this particular case, I think (I have OED2 at home, no subscription to OED3) the cited sense was no longer extant after maybe 1600 or so.  3. The usual meaning (both everyday and technical) of "A unless B" is that B is a necessary but possibly not sufficient condition for *not* A.

Comment: As an example of how obsolete senses are essentially useless for this purpose, consider that "nice" (from L. *nescius*) once meant "ignorant" and "silly" (from G. *seely*) once meant "happy."  They almost switched places.

Comment: The basis for sense A is basically "on less than."  The typical usage in this era (before 1600) was on the order of "Not A on less than B," meaning that A would not happen on any condition lower than B.  Over time, the "not" and "than" (occasionally "that") dropped away so that more or less the same sense was conveyed by "A unless B."  (I've modernized the spellings in all examples.)

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for explaining it. Shame this question was closed. If you posted an answer, I would upvote and accept! "Please do not use links on Math.SE that are behind paywalls." I did link tot a screenshot in my post. Did you want me to show it in line?

Comment: f I understand you, "A on less than B" means "Not A if not B". Can you please elaborate how "on less than" meant "not"?

Comment: "On" here means something like "if"; "less than" means "not (yet)."  I don't think I noticed the screenshot when I made my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably too long for a comment.

First, “$p$ unless $q$” is explained in your first link as “if not $q$, then $p$”, which seems exactly right to me.

As for dictionary definitions, my American Heritage Dictionary says, “except on the condition that”, in other words, that $p$ will be the case at all times, the only possible exceptions occurring when $q$ holds.

To my mind, the two say the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to work and start solely from Definition 1 above. I'm uncertain if your answer does?

Comment: It absolutely does not, @Edge . That’s why I would toss the edition of the Oxford Dictionary that you’re using into the waste-bin.

Comment: No.  That entry *specifically* denotes an obsolete use.  The OED is not worthless, but this application is.